# Multiple key strokes not working in seleinum

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a canvas and there i need to press CTRL + SHIFT + V. When i press these keys a window shall pop up and i have to read the text from it.

I'm using IE11 and .Net. The issue is while using selenium grid.

I tried this but it does not work. Any clue?

```
Canvas.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Shift + "V")
```

I also tried with the ascii value of v \u0056 but that also does not seem to work.

Added the complete method to replicate the issue.

```
public void TestMethod1()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();

        // When set the HasNativeEvents the send keys works fine but that is a restriction i can't do that.
        //cap.SetCapability(CapabilityType.HasNativeEvents, false);

        webdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://someip:port/wd/hub"), cap);
        webdriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
        webdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://someip:port");
        webdriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("OpenCanvas")).Click();
        IWebElement ele = webdriver.FindElement(By.Id("canvasID"));
        Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        ele.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Shift + 'v'); // this should open a pop up but it fails
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        string after_markup = webdriver.FindElement(By.Id("DialogText")).Text;
        Assert.AreEqual("some test string", after_markup, "Failed to draw markup on 3D model");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Upon researching how to send multiple keys in C#, it looks like if you pass the character string "V" as a lowercase "v", it should work.

So try:

`Canvas.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Shift + "v");`

Hope that works for you.

Comment: I'm using C# and could not find Keys.chord. Could you tell me the equivalent in C#?

Comment: See my updated answer. Hope that works for you. It seems like the issue with C# sending multiple keys is that the character must be lowercase.

Comment: No, there are no errors. SendKeys are passed silently but does not have any affect.

Comment: Can you post your whole test class? Something isn't right.

Comment: Added the test method.

Comment: Try: `action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys(String.("v").perform();`

Comment: I think the above syntax is for java, so i converted the c# equivalent as:              action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Shift).SendKeys("v").Perform() but that didn't helped.